# Are Unity's ScriptableObjects secure

Tags: unity-game-engine

I understand the basic premise of ScriptableObjects but one thing keeps bugging me.

Atm I have a `class which has a List<Level>`. `Level` is a struct and has a `bool property isFree` which defines whether the level is free or paid. Whenever a player attempts to load a level from `List<Level>` I check if the player has access to the level in question and either load it or send them to the store.

I'm planing to refactor my code to use ScriptableObjects, each of which will define a level. What I'm concerned is that these objects *live as asset* files. Does this mean that a person can open said files and flip the switch on the level from free to paid, or are the files editable when editing the game and not after it is build and run?

I assume that the answer is the later, otherwise editing SO of weapons and character stats would make cheating trivial.

Comment: The game’s resources are built into a file. Since you are using in app purchases, you are probably on mobile. If someone could modify the files of your game, they could do pretty much anything, including decompile your game and rebuild it with changes. However, for most games, this will not be common enough to be worth worrying about.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b thank you for your comment. With `if someone could modify the files of your game` do you mean reverse engineering the files or that the files are in plain text and can be easily opened with any editor to change the values. Files here refers to SO files.

Comment: They are not plain text that I know of but Unity decompilers exist. I meant that for example on mobile, it is difficult to get the app onto a platform where you could modify it, whereas on desktop platforms, someone could grab all of the files and decompile them with ease.

Comment: That's how I perceived it but wasn't entirely sure. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you use a struct or a ScriptableObject, they're serialized the same way.  They can, in theory, be deconstructed, edited, and reconstructed, but that kind of thing is exceedingly rare, especially for smaller games.

If you really want to make it "more secure", then don't store it locally.  Have the game make a network check each time it's started up.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Among many articles that I read there was a mention that some people use JSON files in combination with SOs so I got confused whether the SOs stay as plain text files that anyone can just open and change before play.

Answer (score 0):

Technically they are both asset and code. Also technically regular scene files are assets. The asset part is the YAML part of the file, storing references, values etc. SOs still have a code counterpart.

[dnSpy](https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy) can modify your assemblies. So if they try enough, they can change what your code does to a point. Honestly I don't think anyone would bother that much, but consider that any game out there on PC probably has trainers etc. There's nothing you can do to prevent cheating completely. Unity games are not as trivial to cheat though, e.g. with sth like CheatEngine. Really depends.

EDIT:

> but that kind of thing is exceedingly rare, especially for smaller games.

I agree with Louis.